# How can I place the default value in the input text box

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-controller

I have the below code. I want to have the default value assigned to the script variables initially shown in the box. Later the value must change according to user's input in the text box.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Hello app </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="testapp">
        <p> Enter your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
        <p> Enter your age here: <input type="text" ng-model="age"> </p>
        <ol>
          <li> My Name is {{ name }} </li>
          <li>I am {{ age}} years old </li>
        </ol>

       <script>
       var app = angular.module("testapp",[]);
       app.controller=("test", function($scope){
       $scope.age = "20"
       $scope.name = "zigo"
       });
       </script>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I want "20" and "zigo" to be initially shown in the text box. How can i change my code?

Comment: i guess you are looking fir angular js not angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing **`ng-controller`** in html and the controller should be,

```
 app.controller("test", function($scope){
```

**NOT**

```
app.controller=("test", function($scope){
```

**DEMO**

```js
  var app = angular.module("testapp",[]);
 app.controller("test", function($scope){
       $scope.age = "20"
       $scope.name = "zigo"
 });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Hello app </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="test">
        <p> Enter your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
        <p> Enter your age here: <input type="text" ng-model="age"> </p>
        <ol>
          <li> My Name is {{ name }} </li>
          <li>I am {{ age}} years old </li>
        </ol>
 
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. You forgot to mention your test controller in the `<div>`.

[Edited version of your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ehl8HLT9frxF81RXnM0u?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var app = angular.module("testapp",[]);
 app.controller("test", function($scope){
       $scope.age = "20"
       $scope.name = "zigo"
 });
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Hello app </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="test">
        <p> Enter your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
        <p> Enter your age here: <input type="text" ng-model="age"> </p>
        <ol>
          <li> My Name is {{ name }} </li>
          <li>I am {{ age}} years old </li>
        </ol>

   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```